# ¿Cómo llamar a procedimientos almacenados de PostgreSQL desde Ruby On Rails?

Tags: postgresql, ruby-on-rails, stored-procedure

Estoy trabajando en *Ruby on Rails* con la Base de datos *PostgreSQL*, tengo instaladas las gemas siguientes:

> ```
> gem 'pg', '~> 1.2', '>= 1.2.3'
> gem 'activerecord-postgresql-adapter', '~> 0.0.1'
> ```

Debo hacer el llamado de procedimientos almacenados que se encuentran en la Base de datos de *PostgreSQL* y no he encontrado la forma aún.

¿Existe la forma de hacer el llamado como *Oracle*?, por ejemplo, con *Oracle* realizando la siguiente configuración/instalación puedo hacer el llamado de procedimientos almacenados creados en la Base de datos de *Oracle*:

1. En el archivo *Gemfile.yml*:

   > ```
   > gem 'ruby-plsql' 
   > gem 'ruby-oci8' 
   > gem 'activerecord-oracle_enhanced-adapter'
   > ```
2. Inicializador que lo conecte a su conexión *ActiveRecord*, esto se hace creando un archivo *plsql.rb* en la carpeta *config* `config/plsql.rb`, el inicializador es el siguiente:

   ```
   plsql.activerecord_class = ActiveRecord::Base
   ```

Con esta configuración en *Oracle* puedo hacer el llamado a una función de la siguiente forma:

```
plsql.Nombre_Paquete.Nombre_Funcion( nombre_parametro1, nombre_parametro2 )
```

Estoy buscando hacer el llamado pero esta vez con *PostgreSQL*.

Answer (score 1):

No existe una manera directa en rails donde se haya abstraído el uso de proc. almac.. Por tanto la forma que tienes es llamando a un comando SQL directamente con `.execute`:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute('CALL tu_proced_alamac')
```

También puedes usar cualquier modelo de ActiveRecord que tengas definido:

```
Usuario.connection.execute('CALL tu_proced_alamac')
```